# How to unify the time reported by server and docker of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I realized that the time of Apache IoTDB server is not correct, right know it reported: 2023-02-07 08:29:56, 997. However, I checked the time of the docker, and the docker time is correct, which reported: 2023-02-07 04:52:04 PM CST. Anyone know what may be the reason for this time difference and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on your creation of web bridge for Apache IoTDB, to see if you unify the time of server and docker from there.